# Prove that u(x) is in $L^{\infty}\left(B(0,1)\right)$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Let $B(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $N>1$. And the function
$$u(x):=\ln\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)\right),\quad x\in B(0,1)\backslash \{0\}$$

How can I prove that $u\notin L^{\infty}\left(B(0,1)\right)$?

Comment: Hint. Let $M>0$. By definition, you need to show to show that $|u(x)|>M$ on a set of nonzero measure. Can you manage to find such a set? Since the function is radially decreasing and radially symmetric, the main candidate for such a set would be a small ball $B(0,\delta)$ with $\delta=\delta(M)$ chosen accordingly. So, can you choose $\delta$ small enough such that $|u|$ is larger than $M$ on the ball of radius $\delta$?

Comment: I think that $\delta=\frac{1}{e^{e^{M}}-1}$ and take $B(0,\delta)$

Comment: Now, I don't know if that same delta works when $u(x)<0$

Comment: It is true that $u$ is not positive on the whole domain. But for the sake of proving that the function is not in $L^\infty$, it is enough to find *one* region of the domain on which $u$ is not essentially bounded. In particular, note that $u$ is positive, say, for $|x|<1/100$, and it is somewhat clear that $u$ is unbounded for $x$ close to zero, so you can simply choose $\delta$ in such a way that $\delta<1/100$. The only important thing is that $\delta>0$. The $\delta$ you chose looks quite nice anyway, it seems to me that in the ball $B(0,\delta)$, with that $\delta$, you have $u>0$.